# django: Create custom user with email as login and other fields

Tags: django, django-users

I am using Django 2.0.3. I want email as the username and also First Name and Last Name as required fields.

Apart from this,later the user can update the gavtar (models.ImageField) and aboutme (models.CharField(max_length=140)), dateofbirth, country, city.

After looking through lot of articles on net, i found the only way to achieve this is to use AbstractBaseUser and define each field.

So what is the best way to do this in Django.

Comment: Django provides a very nice tutorial on that topic: [Customizing authentication in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/)

Comment: After looking through lot of articles on net and  Customizing authentication in Django , i found the only way to achieve this is to use AbstractBaseUser and define each field. Is that right

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi I think, Yes

Comment: I will be great if you can share some link also.

Comment: As described in the tutorial I linked above, there are two ways of implementing the custom user model: [Extending the existing User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) or [Substituting a custom User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model). What you want is the second approach.

Comment: In [Specifying a custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) we see that your suggestion of inheriting `AbstractBaseUser` is the correct one.

Comment: but i also want the django's Admin. Is it possible with this

Comment: i got one link to demonstrate https://github.com/pshrmn/notes/blob/master/django/users.md

Comment: Just subclass `UserAdmin`.

Comment: Also if i want to change (add, remove or edit) some of the fields, is it possible in the later stage.  or only the first migration  is the final one